# How to fix and convert sql union all to linq

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, group-by, union

I have two table:

```
create table A          
(
    Id              uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
    Success         int,
    Failed          int,
    CreatedOn       datetime default getdate() not null 
)
go

create table B
(
    Id              uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
    Email           varchar(150),    
    Mark            float,                       
    CreatedOn       datetime default getdate() not null
)
go


insert into A values(NEWID(), 3, 9, '2011-11-10 07:56:14.933')
insert into A values(NEWID(), 8, 3, '2011-11-30 10:56:14.933')
insert into A values(NEWID(), 2, 13, '2011-08-11 17:56:14.933')
insert into A values(NEWID(), 22, 4, '2010-12-15 21:56:14.933')

insert into B values(NEWID(),'Email 1', 9, '2011-10-10 07:56:14.933')
insert into B values(NEWID(),'Email 2', 9, '2010-10-10 07:56:14.933')
insert into B values(NEWID(),'Email 3', 9, '2009-10-10 07:56:14.933')
insert into B values(NEWID(),'Email 4', 9, '2008-10-10 07:56:14.933')
```

Single statement:

```
SELECT SUM(Success) as TotalSuccess, SUM(Failed) as TotalFailed
FROM  A
--WHERE CreatedOn = (1)
GROUP BY MONTH(CreatedOn) -- (3)

SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalEmail
FROM B
--WHERE CreatedOn = (2)
GROUP BY MONTH(CreatedOn) -- (3)
```

If you run two single statement successfully.
I have the following Transact SQL query using a UNION ALL to included two statements but error.

```
SELECT  SUM(Success), SUM(Failed), TotalEmail, CreatedOn 
FROM (SELECT  Success, Failed, 0 as TotalEmail, CreatedOn
          FROM A
         --WHERE CreatedOn = (1) 
         UNION ALL
        SELECT  0 as Success, 0 as Failed, COUNT(*) as TotalEmail, CreatedOn
          FROM B
         --WHERE CreatedOn = (2) 
         ) SomeThing
GROUP BY MONTH(CreatedOn) -- (3)
```

(1), (2): if user select all years then not WHERE/ may be year - month/all months - day/all day

(3): if user select all years then not GROUP BY/ if user selected year -> group by month, if user selected month -> group by day

How to fix and this would look in LINQ i.e some examples wouldbe nice or if anyone can recommend a good tutorial on UNION ALL in linq.

**EDIT** I have rewritten the LINQ query to this and fixed my error:

```
var query = (_model.A.GroupBy(s1 => s1.CreatedOn.Month)
                        .Select(g => new  
                                {
                                    CountFailed = g.Sum(item => item.Failed),
                                    CountSuccess = g.Sum(item => item.Success),
                                    CountEmail = 0,
                                    Month = g.Key
                                }))
                .Concat(_model.B.GroupBy(s2 => s2.CreatedOn.Month)
                        .Select(myGroup => new  
                                {
                                    CountFailed = 0,
                                    CountSuccess = 0,
                                    CountEmail = myGroup.Count(),
                                    Month = myGroup.Key,
                                }));
var result = query.GroupBy(q => q.Month).Where(myGroup => myGroup.Count() > 0)
                .Select(myGroup => new  
                        {
                            CountFailed = myGroup.Sum(item => item.CountFailed),
                            CountSuccess = myGroup.Sum(item => item.CountSuccess),
                            CountEmail = myGroup.Sum(item => item.CountEmail),
                            Month = myGroup.Key
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Concat` method.look [How to: Concatenate Two Sequences (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979.aspx)

Comment: I try as follow: 
var result =(from s1 in _model.A
group s1 by s1.CreatedOn.Month into g
select new{
CountFailed = g.Sum(item => item.Failed),
CountSuccess = g.Sum(item => item.Success),
CountEmail = 0,
Created = g.Key
})
.Concat(from s2 in _model.B
 group s2 by s2.CreatedOn.Month into myGroup
 select new
 {
CountFailed = 0,
CountSuccess = 0,
CountEmail = myGroup.Count(),
Created = myGroup.Key,
});
but return: two month 10 and two month 11 
http://i.imgur.com/LCzRV.png how to merge result?